# Sybase 2762 - The 'Create table' command not allowed within a multi-statement transation in the 'tempdb' database" - ON OLD STOR PROC

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, sybase, ase

I have got the following error Sybase 2762 - The 'Create table' command not allowed within a multi-statement transation in the 'tempdb' database"  - ON OLD STOR PROC

The database settings are what is expected : sp_dboption, ddl in tran set to 'true'

This is an old procedure that has not been changed and was working well before.
However, we have recently performed a major release on the server.

My question is, would dropping and recreating the procedure help?

This is a production error.

Comment: Do you have multiple temporary databases and if so, have you verified 'ddl in tran' is enabled/true for all temporary databases (including 'tempdb')?

Comment: you can run commit before the table creation then try

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error in any database - be it user database or tempdb (if the table name starts with # or explicitly specified in tempdb), it specifies the database name. Same can be verified from [official site](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABFDFIB.htm):

```
The '%s' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the '%.*s' database.
```

As mentioned by [markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso), you can have multiple tempdb based on system requirement of your application.

Please use  that database and enable "ddl in tran" option as below:

```
USE master
go
exec sp_dboption 'db_name', 'ddl in tran', true
go
USE db_name
go
checkpoint
go
```

I hope this would solve underlying issue. Dropping and recreating procedure is not required.